# Postman call to get S3 Bucket Location Fails for regions other than "us-east-1"

Tags: amazon-s3, postman

In POSTMAN,

I am using the below GET request to get the location of my S3 bucket.

Request Type : GET

API          : https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/?location

Authorization: I am choosing AWS Signature and I am passing the Access and 
               secret keys. and given Service Name as s3.

But the Problem is, 
By default Auhorization takes "us-east-1" as the region and creates the signature out of it.

So for us-east-1 region buckets, this call works well.

But when i use this reuqest to get the location of bucket(which are present in other regions than "us-east-1") , this call fails as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code>
<Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' 
is wrong; expecting 'us-west-2'</Message>
<Region>us-west-2</Region>
....
....
</Error>
```

Can anyone suggest a solution, if there any?

Comment: For finding the 
bucket location, `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname` should do the trick, with us-east-1 in auth, regardless of bucket region.  Give that try?

Comment: Yes i tried. When we do that it throws below error.

<Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' 
is wrong; expecting 'us-west-2'</Message>

Comment: @aravindp03 did you find the issue?

Comment: Hi all, I found solution by setting the s3_host variable in the .boto file